# Creating an imageview without using XML in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to create an `Imageview` programmatically without using `XML`. Is there any way to create it using the height, width and margin property.

Is it possible to add multiple component like this to different places of the screen using the height, width and margin property?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code you can use. It relies on the fact that your container is a RelativeLayout:

```
ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
params.topMargin = myTopMargin;
params.leftMargin = myLeftMargin;

myImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
myImageView.setImageResource(R.id.my_image_resource);

myRelativeLayout.addview(myImageView);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

**`imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`**

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            //ImageView Setup
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            //setting image resource
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            //setting image position
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//setting image margin
MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(image.getLayoutParams());
marginParams.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            //adding view to layout
            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            //make visible to program
            setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Hope this will help..

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        //ImageView Setup
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        //setting image resource
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        //setting image position
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //adding view to layout
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
        //make visible to program
        setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
                    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                    //ImageView Setup
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                    //setting image resource
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.something);
                    //setting image position
//set the margin to the layoutparams
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    //add view to layout
                    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
                    //make visible to program
                    setContentView(linearLayout);
```